# Why would an implementation of getwd call mktemp?

Tags: c, software-development, file-system, bugs, sunos

As mentioned [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2782874/how-to-catch-unintentional-function-interpositioning) the book *Expert C Programming* contains the claim that there was a bug in SunOS 4.0.3's version of `lpr`, (a printing program) caused by a custom `mktemp` function overriding the library function of the same name when called by `getwd`.

The example code describing the problem was:

#### my_source.c

```
mktemp() { ... }

main() {
  mktemp();
  getwd();
}
```

#### libc

```
mktemp(){ ... }
getwd(){ ...; mktemp(); ... }
```

My assumption is that `getwd` is meant to get the current working directory, and `mktemp` is meant to make a temporary file name, like, if not identical to the linux functions with the [same](https://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man3/getwd.3.html) [names](https://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man3/mktemp.3.html).

My question is, why would `getwd` call `mktemp`? That is, why would the function to get the working directory, need to make a temporary file name?

The only possible reason I can think of is that sometimes you end up with a process that doesn't have a real working directory, so a temporary one is returned. But that doesn't seem likely to me. Also, if that was the reason, why would processes end up without working directories often enough that it was a noticeable problem?

Comment: What does the documentation of the actual `getwd()` say? Did you try to find source code (Solaris as a branch was at times open source)? Additionally BSD and Linux implementations might also give some hint.

Answer (score 20, accepted):

If you look into the source code for SunOS 4.1.4, [available online](https://winworldpc.com/download/7a2ac39a-c5be-c3a9-c5b8-11c3a5c28f13), `getwd()` is *not* a simple function.

It actually walks up the directory tree, performing all sorts of wonderful tasks to get the name of the parent directory and prefix it to your current directory name. It does that because it wants to get an *absolute* location, independent of any hard links, mounts across device boundaries, and other file-system trickery like circular links.

In other words, it wants to ensure that things like `/1/2/3/4/5/4/6` (where that `5` is a hard link back to the `3`) give you the correct `/1/2/3/4/6` (it's more than just `.` and `..` that can cause this issue).

Hence it calls `stat("./")` to get device information of your current directory, then continuously calls `stat("../")` to walk up the tree, checking things like device crossings and so on. It only stops when it comes to the root of the entire hierarchy (the parent is the same device and inode as the current).

While this version of the code doesn't mention `mktemp`, it seems plausible to me that an earlier one *may* have resorted to the use of that function to (for example) establish whether a particular directory was accessible to the user. The code linked to simply checks whether the `stat` call returned an error but I've not been able to find the 4.0.3 source in easily accessible format.

Comment: Sounds plausible.